# Why sympy can't calculate?

Tags: python, sympy

```
    import sympy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set
Cd = 0.25
g = 9.81
pf = 10**(-6)  # Perturbation Fraction
t = 4
v = 36
xr = [int(input('initial guess : '))]
i = 0
Ea = 1
Es = 0.01

# 함수 정의
def f(m):
    return sp.sqrt(g * m / Cd) * sp.tanh(sp.sqrt(g * Cd / m) * t) - v

# real root
x = sp.Symbol('x')
ans = sp.solve(f(x))  # sp.solve()로 해 구하기
print(ans)
```

i want to get real root of f(x).
but this code have some problem in line for # real root
i can't figure out

Answer (score 2):

You should not expect sympy to do miracles. Beyond relatively simple symbolic manipulations, sympy just get stuck, sometimes even returning wrong answers. You have to turn to commercial tools such as Maple or Mathematica in order to crack tough nuts.

Your alternative in most practical cases is to use scipy and get a good numeric solution, which is what you want most of the time rather than a closed form solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sympy is a symbolic math library, trying to find exact symbolic solutions. As such, it doesn't work well with floats, as they are necessarily imprecise.

If your equations are fully numeric, it is usually recommended to employ numeric libraries such as numpy and scipy. If you're already doing symbolic manipulations (e.g. calculating differentials), sympy provides `nsolve` which calls a numeric solver. As such, it also needs a seed to start its numeric search. In your case it would look like:

```py
# ....
xr = 1
ans = sp.nsolve(f(x), xr)
```

Result: `142.737633108449`

Sympy also has a way to convert a sympy function to numpy format (in numpy things work much faster, but there are no symbolic expressions). `sp.lambdify(x, f(x))` creates such a numpy function. Here is how it would look like with your example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f_np = sp.lambdify(x, f(x))
xi = np.linspace(1, 1000, 2000)
plt.plot(xi, f_np(xi))
```

[image: plotting the lambdified function]

In an interactive environment, you can [add a question mark](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html#accessing-help) to display the numpy source of the function:

```
>>> f_np?
Signature: f_np(x)
Docstring:
Created with lambdify. Signature:
func(x)
Expression:
6.26418390534633*sqrt(x)*tanh(6.26418390534633*sqrt(1/x)) - 36
Source code:
def _lambdifygenerated(x):
    return (6.26418390534633*sqrt(x)*tanh(6.26418390534633*sqrt(x**(-1.0))) - 36)
```

Comment: All the parameters should be declared as symbols not floating point constants. An attempt to solve the equation can then be made (which will probably fail as previously mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your expression for `f(x)` you will see that it is highly non-linear (as also shown in the plot that JoahnC showed you):

```
6.26418390534633*sqrt(x)*tanh(6.26418390534633*sqrt(1/x)) - 36
```

SymPy cannot give an analytical solution for something that has no such solution. It can, however, give numerical approximations for univariate expressions. That's what `nsolve` is for. It needs an initial guess for the solution (as you anticipated by asking for `xr`).

```
>>> sp.nsolve(f(x), 100)
142.737633108449
```